# Gatsby with Elastic Search UI, <SearchProvider> breaks SSR

Tags: gatsby, elastic-appsearch, elastic-search-ui

Im building a page on Gatsby, and the site uses Elastic Cloud, with their `search ui` components. Pretty nice library actually, but I have a major problem.

If I have one `<SearchProvider>` wrapping the `<SearchBox>` in the header and one  to wrap the search result page they seem to live two different lives. And that's kind of expected when you think about it.

So, I thought to my self:

> Aha, all search functionality must of course inherit from the same
> `<SearchProvider>`!

So, I added it to `gatsby-browser.js` and `gatsby-ssr.js`, like so:

**gatsby-browser.js**

```js
import './src/styles/global.scss';
    
import { SearchProvider } from '@elastic/react-search-ui';
import React from 'react';
    
import { searchDriver } from './src/components/search/search-driver';
    
export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return <SearchProvider config={searchDriver()}>{element}</SearchProvider>
};
```

**gatsby-ssr.js:**

```js
import { SearchProvider } from '@elastic/react-search-ui';
import React from 'react';
    
import { searchDriver } from './src/components/search/search-driver';
    
export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return <SearchProvider config={searchDriver()}>{element}</SearchProvider>
};
```

Here comes the issue, **it breaks the entire HTML server rendering**. Instead I just get an "empty" DOM from the server. The page then renders using JS. So, the page *look* fine, but no HTML is rendered on the server, which is kind of the thing with Gatsby.

I have tried to fix this bug for multiple days, any help greatly appreciated!

**Related links:**

> This is useful to set up any context providers that will wrap your application

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#wrapRootElement

> The SearchProvider is a React wrapper around the Headless Core

https://docs.elastic.co/search-ui/api/react/search-provider